# Send SSH command to Raspberry Pi via Android App

Tags: android, python, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am currently learning and playing with a Raspberry Pi B+ V1.2.

After connecting a LED with the Pi and being able to run it using a python file
I would like to run this file using a simple button click on an Android App.
Additionally, I want to use a SSH connection.

In short:

**Toggle_Button_Click -> send command(e.g. `sudo python gpiohigh.py`) 
-> LED turns on
Toggle_Button_Click -> send command(e.g. `sudo python gpiolow.py`) 
-> LED turns off**

This is the general idea but I am a beginner. I've searched tons of posts(mentioning and including JSCH) but they could not help me out.

Could anyone help me out by telling me where I should start?

Thank you very much!

*Taka*

Comment: `I want to use the already opened SSH connection.`. Please tell how you opened such a connection.

Comment: I connected with SSH using the Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: @Taka you really want to direct tru that ubuntu connection? Why not just create a new connection whenever you send the commands?

Comment: `connected with SSH using the Ubuntu terminal`. ??? You connected your Android device with  RasPi using an Ubuntu terminal? Please come to the point!

Comment: I just remotely accessed to the pi using SSH with the Ubuntu terminal. Then I created python files in order to turn the LEDs on. That's all I have done until now, because I have no clue where to go on right now.

@EL3PHANTEN In the end I want to click a button on an Android app that I want to create which is giving a SSH signal to the pi telling him to run those files mentioned above.

I hope we are all on the same page now.

Comment: @Taka okey if we are on the same page, hopefully you dont want to use an allready open SSH connection, as you say in the question. But rather create a new connection (as you should do) when you click on something on android.

Comment: Right, I just edited it - it was my fault and very distracting sorry!